# How to deserialize a Map of Arrays in Simple Framework?

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to `deserialize` following `xml`:

```xml
<scenario name="test responses">
    <cmd name="query1">
        <return>success_200.xml</return>
        <return>error_500.xml</return>
    </cmd>
    <cmd name="query2">
        <return>success_200.xml</return>
    </cmd>
</scenario>
```

into this class

```
@Root(name="scenario")
public class TestScenario {
    @ElementMap(entry="cmd", key="name", attribute=true, inline=true)
    private Map<String,StepsList> scenario;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String name = "";

    public static class StepsList {
        @ElementList(name="return")
        private List<String> steps = new ArrayList<String>();

        public List<String> getSteps() {
            return steps;
        }
    }
}
```

But get a `org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException`: Unable to satisfy `@org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList`

How it can be done?

Comment: Check this:  http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after couple hours of research, I created a working solution.

Strange enough, but to create a map of arrays you need to use `@ElementList` decoration with special SimpleFramework utility class `Dictionary`. Objects inserted into that dictionary must implement `Entry` interface and can contain any parsing rules. In my case they contain `List<String>` corresponding to inner `<return>` tags.

You can read about utility classes in the tutorial: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#util

```
@Root(name="scenario")
public class TestScenario {
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private Dictionary<StepsList> scenario;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String name = "";

    public Dictionary<StepsList> getScenario() {
        return scenario;
    }

    @Root(name="cmd")
    public static class StepsList implements Entry {
        @Attribute
        private String name;

        @ElementList(inline=true, entry="return")
        private List<String> steps;

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<String> getSteps() {
            return steps;
        }
    }
}
```

`Dictionary` is a class implementing `java.util.Set`, and you can use it like this:

```
TestScenario test = loadScenario("test.xml");
String step1 = test.getScenario().get("query1").getSteps().get(0);
// step1 is now "success_200.xml"
String step2 = test.getScenario().get("query1").getSteps().get(1);
// step2 is now "error_500.xml"
```

Comment: i am interested, can you explain what is going on?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify

Comment: Thank you, but i don't see map but there is a List >

Comment: Updated answer again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ElementList(required = false, inline = true, name="return")
private List<String> steps = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Now it throws an `org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'return' does not have a match`